# Unicode Tables in Vim

Tags: vim, fonts, unicode

I have been toying around with i3 and like many others ran into a few snags working with Unicode characters. The majority of them resolved by installing fonts or pointing config files to the installed fonts. Now out of curiosity I've been poking at this unicode.vim plugin, and am having issues getting the unicode tables to display the characters within. I'd like to use the unicode auto completion feature of unicode.vim, but with most characters within the tables displayed as empty boxes it has pretty limited use.

I guess I'm not sure if this is normal or not - Is there something I can do to configure vim / my terminal (Urxvt -> tmux on i3) to display most or all of the characters within the table? I'd like to be able to use this table to quickly search up new symbols instead of using a web browser and finding a code / font online. I've spent a considerable amount of time reading through man pages and wiki with no luck. Hoping someone can point me in the right direction, this would really speed up my use of these symbols. I'm really looking for a way to lookup unicode symbols quickly without having to open a web browser. Thanks!

[image: Boxes in Unicode table]

Comment: I guess you just  need a proper font because current font lack of some glyphs for some code point

Answer (score 0):

Unicode characters will be displayed as long as the 1) application supports it, 2)you have locales set to UTF-8, and 3) you have the appropriate fonts.

In the case of urxvt it supports Unicode. So one way to check you have the right configuration is to see if the  symbols display well on your browser.

Once  unicode is working on your terminal it will work on vim without the need for any vim plugins or modifications.